# How to define Kubernetes Job using a private docker registry?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-registry

I have a simple Kubernetes job (based on the http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/jobs/work-queue-2/ example) which uses a Docker image that I have placed as a public image on my dockerhub account. It all loks like this:

**job.yaml**:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: job-wq-2
spec:
  parallelism: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      name: job-wq-2
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: c
        image: jonalv/job-wq-2
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Now I want to try to instead use a private Docker registry which requires authentication as in:

`docker login https://myregistry.com`

But I can't find anything about how I add username and password to my job.yaml file. How is it done?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use [ImagePullSecrets](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/images/#specifying-imagepullsecrets-on-a-pod).

Once you create a secret object, you can refer to it in your pod spec (the `spec` value that is the parent of `containers`:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: job-wq-2
spec:
  parallelism: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      name: job-wq-2
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: myregistrykey
      containers:
      - name: c
        image: jonalv/job-wq-2
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Ofcourse, you'll have to create the secret (as per the docs). This is what this will look like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: myregistrykey
  namespace: mynamespace
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: UmVhbGx5IHJlYWxseSByZWVlZWVlZWVlZWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGx5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eSBsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbG9vb29vb29vb29vb29vb29vb29vb29vb29vb25ubm5ubm5ubm5ubm5ubm5ubm5ubm5ubmdnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2cgYXV0aCBrZXlzCg==
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

The value of `.dockerconfigjson` is a base64 encoding of this file: `.docker/config.json`.

The key point: **A job spec contains a pod spec**. So whatever knowledge you gain about pod specs can be applied to jobs as well.

Comment: It's also possible to create the Secret as `kubectl create secret docker-registry my-secret --docker-server=DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER --docker-username=DOCKER_USER --docker-password=DOCKER_PASSWORD --docker-email=DOCKER_EMAIL` I found out from: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_create_secret_docker-registry/